# Nginx websoket reverse proxy caching

Tags: nginx, cache, websocket

I'm currently using nginx to reverse proxy a websocket based application. Can I enable caching websocket messages to make the application available when service behind is down? I know caching is possible for HTTP requests as [documented here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/). Is there any way I can achieve this without writing my own caching layer from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as websocket caching. Websocket is simply a messaging protocol. It transmits arbitrary messages back and forth.

Comment: thank you for answering. In my case a token is used to match requests and response. I accept your answer; since websocket is generally used for full duplex communication, this requirement may not have high demand right now.